# Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.mailtrap.io:465

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

Hello i'm using 'maven' in eclipse.. i tried to send the mails using smtp.mailtrap.io but its showing these errors. Please find a solution for me

```
Email email = new SimpleEmail();
email.setHostName("smtp.mailtrap.io");
email.setSmtpPort(2525);
email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("chipurichetti.tarun@*****.com", "****"));
email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
email.setFrom("user@gmail.com");
email.setSubject("TestMail");
email.setMsg("This is a test mail ... :-) sent through gmail smtp after enabling (https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)");
email.addTo("ashokreddy.arikatla@*****.com");
email.send();
System.out.print("mail sent");
```

This is the code i have used

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: its showing something like this.

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp.mailtrap.io:465
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
 at emailsent.sendemail.main(sendemail.java:22)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;

Comment: I think issue is in your hosting url "smtp.mailtrap.io" Are you created account in "mailtrap.io" ? is account in free version or paid version ?

Comment: yes, i have an account in the mailtrap. Its free version.

I tried using smtp.gmail.com.. its working fine with it.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

During my testing with mailtrap.io I discovered that SSL is not supported due to the POODLE vulnerability. Try using TLS/starttls instead of SSL.

Here is the docs for SimpleEmail: [Apache Commons Email Security Docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/userguide.html#Security)

Enforce using STARTTLS by calling `Email.setStartTLSRequired(true)`

When using a secured transport (STARTTLS or SSL) you can force validating the server's certificate by calling `Email.setSSLCheckServerIdentity(true)`. Or can be disabled by specifying `false`.

> **Can I force an encrypted connection?**
>   Yes, you can enforce encrypted connection. Mailtrap SMTP server uses STARTTLS that works over all SMTP ports. We support only TLS connection because of POODLE vulnerability (SSLv2 and SSLv3 are disabled).
>   https://mailtrap.io/faq#faq15

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons why this happens. In my case, it was my Antivirus. I had Avast running, so I uninstalled it (not recommended, you can disable it or something) and it worked.